# Damaged in a crash

Tags: damage, shocks

Hey so a week ago I got a new bike. And when I get something new I try to keep it brand new as long as possible and not taking a single damage, even the touch of wind it makes me feel that damaged it. And today on a corner I slipped because the road it was wet and I fell!
And in that moment I was cursing like hell. I was so angry and stressed because I thought that the fall caused a big damage to the bike. The handle bar is a little scratched but I can get over a aesthetic problem. I just feel that the shock caused some technical issues,for example on the brakes, or the shifter, suspensions etc. I should relax and keep riding peacefully or am I right about it?
Sorry for my english!
Keep riding :)

Comment: Does anything actually feel wrong, or are you just worried that you might have damaged something? At the moment, it's pretty much impossible to answer your question: The only information you've given us is that you fell while going round a corner on a wet road and that the handlebar is scratched but it seems only cosmetic.

Comment: There is a weird sound on the rear wheel. In rest everything is fine, but I'm paranoid

Answer (score 4):

Have you given your bike an M check over?   https://www.sustrans.org.uk/sites/default/files/images/files/migrated-pdfs/frk_bikemcheck.pdf

Do it in a well lit area when you're not rushed.  As long as nothing's wrong then it should be good to ride.